# Attempting to print using typescript is not printing the background image

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to print a page in html using typescript.
After calling the window.print function the background image is not printed.
I have added the style in the header of the print function but the background image is not yet printed

here is the snippet

```
print = function() {
          let printContents, popupWin;
          printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
          popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
          popupWin.document.open();
          popupWin.document.write(`
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>Print Me</title>
                <Style>
                      .bg,tfoot{background:url('../assets/images/img.png'); }
                      .bg{padding-right: 10%;
                      margin-bottom: -0.2% !important;
                      margin-left: -0.1% !important;
                      } 
                  </Style>
              </head>
          <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
            </html>`
          );
          popupWin.document.close();
      }
```

Comment: the style that has the background image never gets printed

Comment: Most browsers (I know Chrome does this) disable background images when printing - you have to manually enable them by ticking the checkbox for **Background Graphics** under **More Settings**. There's no way to enable this by default afaik.

Answer (score -1):

I see 3 possible things that could be causing the background image not to render:

1. The `onload="window.print();window.close()` might be closing the window as soon as soon as the body tag is rendered, therefore you never get to see the contents of your window.
2. The URL reference might be wrong. In order to check this, open the development console (by pressing f12 in your browser) and try looking for any images that the website tried rendering but couldn't find the image.
   [Here is a screenshot of how the developer console looks when it tries rendering a missing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e78Ao.png)
3. Make sure the content you're rendering contains the `bg` class in one of its tags.